# Oracle Function Causes Slow Order By

Tags: sql, oracle

My simple query which uses a function is returning records very fast although there are 20k records, but when Order By is used it takes a long time, here are the scenarios:

1- **select id, MyFunc(id) from MyTable** >>> less than a second (200 ms)

2- **select id, MyFunc(id) from MyTable order by id** >>> more than 60 seconds

3- **select id, MyFunc(id) from MyTable where rownum < 10000 order by id** >>> 2 seconds

Regarding scenario 3, the total records are 20k, so when I limit the result to 10k which is half of the total records then performance is better with 2 seconds, which indicates that I supposed to get 4 seconds if I will retrieve all 20k records, but it is taking more than 60 seconds to fetch all records, so there is something illogical here.

This behavior is only happening when I use a function in my query, but when there is NO function then order by behave in a logical manner.

Comment: Try looking at the EXPLAIN PLAN for each statement and see what the differences are. If that doesn't help you please update your question with these EXPLAIN PLANs

Comment: Are you sure about those timings? Are you sure that the first query is not just returning the first X rows (depending on the fetch size that the database driver specifies) and it is probably not returning the entire result set? The second query has to read the entire table and order it and then return the first X rows (again controlled by the fetch size). The third query has to read the first 10,000 rows (not the entire table) and then order those first 10,000 rows and return the first X of rows from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not measuring the total processing (throughput) time. You are measuring response time to get the first record. Without the `ORDER BY`, there is no buffering step after the function call so as rows come into that step and call the function, the rows are emitted and fetched by the client immediately before the next rows are processed. If you waited until your client fetched *every* row (your client may not be configured by default to do this) instead of just the first page, you'd get a proper idea of how long it's taking.

When you add `ORDER BY` there is an additional buffering step after the rows are generated and the function called for 100% of the rows, and you won't start seeing results until that buffering is complete and 100% of the rows have gone through the function because only then can a sort be done on the results.

When you add `ROWNUM` you limit the # of rows going into the function and sort before cutting it off, so it is only calling the function that many times and so the sort is done pretty quickly. To get response time to approximate actual throughput/full processing time, you'd have to put the `ROWNUM` filter in a parent block like this:

```
select *
  from (select id, MyFunc(id) myfunc_alias from MyTable order by id)
where rownum < 10000
```

This would take just as long as the one without a rownum filter (minus less network traffic of course) because `rownum` isn't computed until after the sort, so 100% of the rows have to go through that function no matter what the rownum cutoff is.

To make this faster you're going to need to tune the function - find where it's spending most of its time (probably in some SQL) and tune that.

Comment: Absolutely true, I am using TOAD and it didn't came to my mind that it inject row-limit to my queries, and the cause was that my function need tuning, many thanks.

Comment: @Akkad, it isn't that Toad injects row limits, it's just that after executing the query when results are available for fetching in batches, it only fetches a few batches before stopping and leaving the remaining rows unfetched. This allows it to return control and not tie up CPU when it figures most folks only care to see the first page or so of results.